Python Flask: Automatically getting or generating SHA-1 fingeriprints
I've created a simple Flask server that runs on HTTPS, accessible by external devices.
When I connect another device (e.g. an ESP8266) I need to provide the SHA-1 fingerprint.
I have no control over the SHA-1 fingerprint that is generated (and I have no idea how it is generated).
So far I've always had to copy and paste the SHA-1 fingerprint from my browser (firefox): I need to visit the server URL through my browser, click on the lock symbol next to the URL, click on "view certificate" and copy and paste the SHA-1 fingerprint.
The SHA-1 fingerprint changes every time I restart the server, so I have to copy and paste it every time (as just described), which is time-consuming.
I was wondering if there was a way to either:

generating MY OWN SHA-1 fingerprint (so that it is always the same every time I launch the server)
OR
automatically getting the SHA-1 fingerprint (maybe through a Flask function?) and printing it on a text file.

I've done some research on the internet but found nothing so far :(
Thank you in advance!
Here's my code:
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    return "Hello World!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, ssl_context='adhoc')


What is the SHA-1 fingerprint relative to?

It is relative to the Flask server. Whenever I start the Flask server and access the URL from a browser (firefox), I can click on the lock symbol that appears before the URL. Then I can click on "View Certificates" and it shows the fingerprints, among which the SHA-1 one.

Please include some code in your question. Specifically the one you use to pass the certificate to the Flask server.

The SHA-1 fingerprint is the SHA-1 hash of the TLS server certificate (the leaf certificate that contains the server DNS name as subjectAlternativeName). https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.Certificate.fingerprint As you don't provide a valid certificate and use the adhock mode, you could simply make a requests to the server after starting it, extract the certificate and generate the hash of it.

@Robert, thank you so much! Solved!

import ssl, hashlib

cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('my_server_url', my_server_port))

pem_cert = ssl.PEM_cert_to_DER_cert(cert)
sha1_fingerprint = hashlib.sha1(pem_cert).hexdigest()
print(sha1_fingerprint)

Thank you so much!
